# DB2 SQL stored function to validate UPC barcode checksum values...?

Tags: db2, db2-400

Has anyone ever seen a DB2 SQL stored function to validate UPC-A or UPC-E barcode checksum values..? Or for that matter, *any* SQL code to do so..?

This is for AS400 DB2 v7r3m0. The barcodes have NUMERIC(14) fields which I like to call "free form" because they have no validation or checksum calculation. Currently no one knows how many of them are correct or not, and I would like to fix that. A validator would tell us if a code is valid, even if it's not the correct one for the product. But baby steps...

I have some Microsoft Access VBA code that I've dabbled with to calculate UPC checksums, but converting that to SQL would be an adventure.

Comment: I think you would be able to find an SQL function fairly easily for a different RDBMS like sql server but then it would have to be adapted to db2 for iSeries. I haven't done this with this exact type of function but rarely when I had for different functions did I find something that I couldn't find an iSeries alternative for the syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126543/sql-proc-to-calculate-check-digit-for-7-and-12-digit-upc https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/06/20/barcode-check-digit-t-sql/

Comment: Oh, after reading that link I've just realized I used the incorrect terminology, and this explains why I felt a bit confused and why a lot of the code I found around the internet seemed so simple. I said I wanted validation (which is true even if I didn't intend it), but the correct term is the checksum or check digit. Sorry for the confusion; I'll update my OP and study that link. I'm a moderate beginner with DB2/PL, but I think I should be able to convert that to a DB2 function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL proc to calculate check digit for 7 and 12 digit upc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126543/sql-proc-to-calculate-check-digit-for-7-and-12-digit-upc)

Comment: Yes it probably is, since I had the terminology confused. And that link will be very helpful.

Comment: It would be easier to code the checksum routine in RPG or JAVA, and call the pgm with an UDF function

Comment: That's possible, but I don't know RPG. But I do know JAVA (or I did when I finally finished my degree two years ago, lol). Does AS400 run JAVA..?

Comment: You have java 8 on your system since it is running V7R3. you can write your java class and call it from an UDF SQL function. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzaha/writeudf.htm

Comment: Oh, I just thought of something. I don't have access to the file system, or I may, but with significant hurdles. Our AS400 system used to be private, until we upgraded to a hosted/shared system last November. So the hosting company would probably want to examine my code with a fine-tooth microscope, and probably with a service fee. But...I'm still going to look into it. That last link you shared has me scratching my chin with temptation.